# error: no matching function for call to 'Entry::Entry()'

Tags: c++, arrays, object, constructor

I'm somewhat familiar to C++, however, there are a few things I don't know. I'm trying to practice with class objects, and in my code, there should be a small array of objects. However, I get a "no matching function for call to" error when compiling, and this error happens when creating the array. I'm stuck, any suggestions?
Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entry{
private:
    string name;
    int num;

public:
    Entry(string name, int num);
    string get_name(){return name;}
    int get_num(){return num;}
    int inc(){
        num++;
        return num;
    }
};

Entry::Entry(string name, int num) {
    this->name = name;
    this->num = num;
}

int main() {
    Entry list[3];

    string name;
    int num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> num;
        list[i] = Entry(name, num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << list[i].get_name() << " : " << list[i].get_num() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Entry list[3];` -- Your `Entry` class lacks a default constructor.  Those elements in that array are created, and the compiler has no way of creating them.

Comment: So I created the default constructor, and it compiles, but doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"?  You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: By default constructor btw he means a constructor without arguments.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/vbkLE0) when default constructor is added.